# Adding text between words of a string

Tags: javascript, html

[what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCOsh.png)

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMOOR.png)

On first image I type in some text, click on button "uppercase" and have an output of this text in uppercase. What I want is the output on image two, where I can add any letters or symbols I want between words of the text. Is it possible?

```js
//upper Case
function upperCaseBtnClicked(){
  const input = document.getElementById('input').value;
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = input.toUpperCase();
}

//lower Case
function lowerCaseBtnClicked(){
  const input = document.getElementById('input').value;
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = input.toLowerCase();
}

//Don't change
function noChangeBtnClicked(){
  const input = document.getElementById('input').value;
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = input;
}
```

```html
 <div class="main">
      <div class="input">
        <label>Write something</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="write" id="input">
      </div>


      <div class="buttons">
        <label>Do it...</label>
      <div class="btns">
        <button onclick="upperCaseBtnClicked()" class="upper_case">uppercase</button>
        <button onclick="lowerCaseBtnClicked()" class="lower_case">lowercase</button>
        <button onclick="noChangeBtnClicked()" class="no_change">don't change</button>
      </div>
      </div>


      <div class="output">
        <p id="output">Here will be you text
        </p>
      </div>


<div class="copy">
  <button class="copy-btn">copy text <i class="fas fa-copy"></i></button>
</div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, just insert random char between words:

```
const chars = ["#", "!", "@", "&", "%", "^", "$", "*", "{", "-", "|"];
const getRandomIndex = () => Math.round(Math.random() * (chars.length - 1));
const mix = (s) => s.split(" ")
                    .map((word)=>`${word} ${chars[getRandomIndex()]}`)
                    .join(" ");

// console.log(mix("this text has five words"));
```

```
//upper Case
function upperCaseBtnClicked(){
  const input = document.getElementById('input').value;
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = mix(input.toUpperCase());
}
```

Comment: Don't use `* 10` . 10 is a magic number. Recall how to get the length of an Array?

Answer (score 0):

assume str=your input string

```
str=str.split()
str.map((el)=>{
if(el.match(/[a-z]/i))
{
//1- convert text to upper case 
//2-print text
return
}
else
{
//1-print text
return
}
})
```

Comment: This does not explain how to insert random characters between words.

Comment: Please learn about [String.prototype.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match). It returns an Array, not a boolean... And your answer still does not explain how to achieve the expected result.

Comment: instead of splitting you could have used `.replace()` and replace one-or-more whitespaces with Space+RandomSymbol+Space

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly and you want to add symbols by editing the output, the easiest ways would be to replace:

```
<p id="output"></p>
with 
<textarea id="output"></textarea>
```

and

```
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = ... 
with
document.getElementById("output").value = ...
```

Comment: Why would `textarea` be more helpful? Don't we have `textContent`? And also, this does not explain how to insert characters inside spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide another example that uses [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace);

```js
const inp = "This text has five words";
const sym = ["##", "@", "^", "&", "**"];
const out = inp.trim().replace(/\s+/g, () => ` ${sym[~~(Math.random()*sym.length)]} `);


console.log(out)
```

The above will first trom whitespaces from the beginning and end of a string, and than replace one-or-more whitespaces `/\s+/g` with a random symbol wrapped in spaces.